# Can't check requested quantity for products without Source Items support issue on 2.3.1

Tags: quantity, third-party-module, magento2.3.1, custom-product-type

I have a custom module installed . A module that adds product type to display a product. On the product configuration, it offers other sets of parameters(Min, max price & total price target to set as success transaction ) that doesn't align to quantity parameter. It do not required the default quantity

This is the error when user click into add to cart
[image: Error encountered]

I believe 1 of these parameters (which is quantity based on error display)is somehow linked & processed when user place the order is unnecessary 
[image: pinpointing issue]

And these are the parameter that module provided to work on the backend
[image: Paramater from module]

I hope someone who has been through a similar situation would kind to share some insight on fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have multiple store or website? and recently migrated from magento 1 to magento 2?

Comment: single store and website,  installed straight from m2, the only issue was the custom module configurations

Comment: Magento 2.3.1 is enabled with multi source inventory (MSI) is your module compatible with magento 2.3.1 check with your module provider.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

New code from Magento 2.3

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="simple" isQty="true" />
    <type name="virtual" isQty="true" />
</config>
```

Check `vendor\vendor\magento\module-catalog-inventory\etc\product_types.xml`

So for your custom product type also add `isQty="true"` in `/etc/product_types.xml`

Comment: This is what I was missing for my extension. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a new product type you need to add `isQty='true'` in the type tag below the file

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/product_types.xml
```

like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="producttype" label="Custom Product Type" modelInstance="Vendor\module\Model\Product\Type\Producttype" isQty="true">
        <priceModel instance="Vendor\module\Model\Product\Price" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code but still same error....
Can't check requested quantity for products without Source Items support