# Can't check requested quantity for products without Source Items support

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

In admin page, I turned on the mode Manage Stock to Yes. After reindex, when I go to product list page, it got an error like this:

[image]

I go to var/log to check what happened, and saw this line:

> Can't check requested quantity for products without Source Items
> support

After search many post in here, I have to temporary fix by delete record in table ui_bookmarks. But it just for a moment, it will be error again later.

How I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: after you fix the ui_bookmark and get back in, use the Columns view editor and uncheck Quantity and Saleable quantity and see if that helps

Comment: not working on that way

Answer (score 0):

Refer this.

[Can't check requested quantity for products without Source Items support issue on 2.3.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272708/cant-check-requested-quantity-for-products-without-source-items-support-issue-o)

Hope it will helps.

If it is not still not fixed then you have to comment the code that added custom column one by one and check which column is use quantity to fetch.

Comment: Hi I checked but we didn't use any third-party extension.

Comment: Is there any new product type added or may be it could be issue with product. we cannot check without checking the log or code

Comment: No any other product type added also debug and system log in the same error without file path.

Answer (score 0):

which magento version?
If magento is >2.3 and you have enabled the MSI (new inventory manager) check if you have the inventory_stock_1 **view**, not table but view.

Also check in your config.php if all module of inventory are enabled; if so follow those steps for fix your issue.

Steps:

- check that there is the default stock: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-stock.html
- go into database and delete the line from table patch_list where patch_name = 'Magento\InventoryCatalog\Setup\Patch\Schema\CreateLegacyStockStatusView'
- bin/magento setup:upgrade

This procedure generate the correct inventory stock view

Cheers

Comment: Hi I checked all is fine but still not working

Comment: no wait, it's not just a check. My comment it's a procedure to do

Comment: Yes I did as well

Comment: the result of this query?
select *
from catalog_product_entity
where sku not in (select sku
                  from inventory_source_item);

Comment: if the result of the query above is different from 0 you have found your problem

Answer (score -1):

Are you running Magento 2.3?

New code from Magento 2.3

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="simple" isQty="true" />
    <type name="virtual" isQty="true" />
</config>
```

Check vendor\vendor\magento\module-catalog-inventory\etc\product_types.xml

So for your custom product type also add isQty="true" in /etc/product_types.xml

Comment: it's already in this path.